# Find longest common date span in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with some stock data. The first column is the datetime and the last column is the ticker/name of the stock. The other columns are price and volume but not relevant here.

Here is the head and tail:

```
    sqlite> select * from History order by dt ASC limit 5;
    "2003-01-02 11:00:00",9.65,9.65,9.65,9.65,1000.0,ACY
    "2003-01-02 11:00:00",62.0,62.0,62.0,62.0,30000.0,AMER
    "2003-01-02 11:00:00",0.345,0.345,0.34,0.34,60000.0,CNR
    "2003-01-02 11:00:00",1.41,1.41,1.41,1.41,45000.0,CRU
    "2003-01-02 11:00:00",32.8,32.85,32.8,32.85,38000.0,DNBNOR
    sqlite> select * from History order by dt DESC limit 5;
    "2010-04-09 19:15:00",3.045,3.05,3.045,3.05,6000.0,ACTA
    "2010-04-09 19:15:00",117.4,117.4,117.1,117.1,14900.0,ACY
    "2010-04-09 19:15:00",3.15,3.15,3.15,3.15,7800.0,AGI
    "2010-04-09 19:15:00",160.25,160.25,160.25,160.25,11300.0,AKER
    "2010-04-09 19:15:00",94.925,94.925,94.65,94.775,32900.0,AKSO
```

As you can see I have data from 2003 to 2010, with around 130 stocks. But not all of the stocks are in the same time range due to mergers, taken of exchange etc.

What I want is to figure out is the (longest) time span which the most stocks have in common, lets say that of the 130 stocks 50 have been around from 2004-2010 and return the date ranges and name of the stocks. Is this possible using SQLite?

Edit: Example on how I think a basic output could look like

```
starttime              endtime                totaltime  stock
"2003-01-02 11:00:00", "2010-04-09 19:15:00", 12345678, ACY
"2003-01-02 11:00:00", "2007-01-07 16:00:00", 12345,    CNR
...
```

Then I could order by `totaltime` to see which stocks have the most data.

Comment: Your question is not 100% clear. Please give an example.

Comment: @TheImpaler, I have now edited in a basic example of how the output could look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take my answer with a grain of salt. I'm not an expert on SQLite but no one else has responded, so the query below "should" work. Try it and improve it as you see fit:

```
with stock_life as (
  select
      stock,
      min(recorded_at) as starttime,
      max(recorded_at) as endtime,
      julianday(max(recorded_at)) - julianday(max(recorded_at)) as totaltime
    group by stock
  )
select * from stock_life
  order by totaltime desc
  limit 50
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work with some minor modifications!